# Htaccess rewriterule wordpress issue

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, http-status-code-500

I'm trying to make this rewriterule via htaccess file in wordpress
I have the following url:
https://domain_name.com/index.php/field/value_to_be_written
and I want it to be internally redirect to:
https://domain_name.com/index.php/field/?get_value=value_to_be_written

I have this following code but it's giving me error 500:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/field/(.*)$ index.php/field/?get_value=$1 [L]
```

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please format your code :)

Comment: If an error with code 500 is thrown, you should see any error message in the server's log. Can you search it and attach it to your question?

Comment: @Guglie Sorry but I'm new here. How can I format my code?

Comment: @molinet you can use 4 spaces indentation or backticks `

Comment: @NicoHaase the point is when i check my error_log file it doesn't display any error message based on this issue. That's why I'm starting to find it pretty weird...

Comment: @Guglie Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need leading slashes:

```
RewriteRule ^/index\.php/field/(.*)$ /index.php/field/?get_value=$1 [L]
```

Excerpt from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

```
<!-- language: lang-none -->
+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| Given Rule                  | Resulting Substitution |
+-----------------------------+------------------------+
| ^/somepath(.*) otherpath$1  | invalid, not supported |
| ^/somepath(.*) /otherpath$1 | /otherpath/pathinfo    |
+-----------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: I'll try later when I get back home and comment the results but thanks in advance for your time and help!

Comment: It may be silly to ask but I have the "RewriteBase /" . Do I still need to add the leading slashes?

Comment: Ok, I tried what you posted and there's no more error 500 but now when I try https://domain_name.com/index.php/field/value_to_be_written it gives me a 404 but the original url https://domain_name.com/index.php/field/?get_value=value_to_be_written is working

Comment: Your rule has the Last flag on it, which means it won't be getting caught by any other rules; and it also rewrites to the same thing. If you're relying on another rule to handle the destination, then you should maybe use `[P]` instead and maybe ideally just make the destination URL have the same destination as the other rule.

Comment: I've been trying to make this work but still gives me error 404 when putting the desired friendly url domain_name.com/index.php/field/value_to_be_written. This is the code I have:  `<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/index\.php/field/(.*)$ /index.php/field/?get_value=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Comment: Try using `[P]` instead of `[L]`

Comment: Sill not working...Thanks anyway for your time and for helping me in first place with error 500 :)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/index\.php/field/?get_value=$1 [L]
```

Please try not sure

Comment: That wouldn't work because it's missing a substitution for the RewriteRule